# GSON can`t deserialize Kotlin class with custom getter

Tags: android, gson, kotlin

Well I have a class

```
class Address {
    var address1: String? = null
}
```

And simple json

```
String jsonString = "{\"address1\":\"test\"}";
```

So all I want to deserialize that, so I just write

```
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Address address = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Address.class);
```

And it works perfectly.

But if I add custom getter

```
class Address {
    var address1: String? = null
        get() = address1 ?: ""
}
```

I`m getting

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at ru.reksoft.okey.models.Address.getAddress1(Address.kt:8)
    at ru.reksoft.okey.models.Address.getAddress1(Address.kt:8)
    //and here are a lot of same lines
```

**So what can I do to make it work properly?**

The one solution I see is removing custom getters at all, but what if I really need them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should work with the `field` instead:

```
class Address {
    var address1: String? = null
        get() = field ?: ""
}
```

The problem is, that using `address1` inside its own setter leads to a recursive call sequence. Instead, the `field` qualifier refers to the [backing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) field. The recursive sequence leads to the `StackOverflowError` you encountered.

But actually, you should also think about the sense of your property: It's declared as a nullable `String`, but you don't allow `null` since you map it to an empty `String`. Is `""` really accepted for the address? It would be much better to simply do `val address1: String = ""`.

Comment: \*Facepalm\*, you are right, that works, thanks =) So stupid mistake from me

Comment: Great. Please consider refactoring the property to a not nullable `String`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access a property in its getter method. Which will in turn call its getter method and so on... Which mean it's calling itself recursively until the exception.

use `field` operator to access its value

```
var address1: String? = null
    get() = field ?: ""
```

**EDIT**

Why allow nullability if it doesn't make any sense?
Let Kotlin take care of the issue. Just do

```
var address1: String = ""
```